# Deactivating DEP to run older video games and applications is it risky?

Tags: windows-7, security, 64-bit, data-execution-prevention

Hello Superuser community.

I am helping my friend get in to some retro gaming via good old games (GOG). And many of the older titles require the DEP to be turned off to function correctly. My question is if I make DEP to be opt out, what kind of risk am I putting my friend under? Any input would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default in Windows 7, and I assume Vista and 8, DEP is only enable for Windows programs and services.  You should not need to change any settings.  There is virtually no risk in leaving it at the default settings.  If for some reason DEP is enabled for all programs and services, you can switch it to the default or disable if for specific programs in services by right clicking My Computer/properties/Advanced/Performance Options/Date Execution Protection.